# tbl_svysummary flip the column order

Tags: r, gtsummary

Is there a way to flip the No and Yes column in the table generated by tbl_svysummary?

```
    data(api, package = "survey")
tbl_svysummary_ex2 <-
  survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = "both", include = c(api00, stype))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to make your by variable a factor, and re-order the levels before passing to `tbl_svysummary()`.

But you can also use `modify_table_body()` to make changes to the underlying data frame that will printed. Example below. (You can use `show_header_names()` to print the underlying column names.)

```r
library(gtsummary)

data(api, package = "survey")

survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) |> 
  tbl_svysummary(by = "both", include = c(api00, stype)) |> 
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x |> dplyr::relocate(stat_1, .after = stat_2)
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Yes**, N = 4,502 | **No**, N = 1,692 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| api00 | 654 (551, 722) | 631 (556, 710) |
| stype |  |  |
| E | 3,791 (84%) | 1,083 (64%) |
| H | 237 (5.3%) | 237 (14%) |
| M | 474 (11%) | 372 (22%) |

<sup>Created on 2024-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>